# Convergence to equilibrium via gradient descent

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, game-theory

J. B. Rosen proved that in concave games of n players (which assumes that Cartesian product of strategy profiles is convex) if the game satisfies the condition of **diagonally strictly concave** then there is a unique Nash equilibrium (see [here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee228a/fa03/228A03/papers/rosen.pdf)).

Suppose that all users follow  gradient descent algorithm (in discrete time space).  Suppose that the game satisfies the **diagonally strictly concave** condition.

> Does the strategy profile converge approximately to unique Nash equilibrium (up to some constant depends on the maximal step size)?

Comment: What does "diagonally strictly concave" mean?

Comment: Definition of diagonally strictly concave: Suppose we have $n$ players with strategies that lies in a convex set $S$. Their  payoff functions $(u_1,..., u_n)$ are diagonally strictly if for every $x^1, x^2 ∈ S$, we have
$(x^1- x^2 )^T \nabla u(x^2) + (x^2 − x^1)^T \nabla u(x^1) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

the paper written by J. B. Rosen , has specified the maximum step size required for the convergence to equilibrium points which is a function of  the cost functions.

Comment: Wow! I missed that. Thank you so much behrad!